# Portable Class library and reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, portable-class-library

I am building new application for Desktop, Windows 8 store and Windows phone at the same time. so I created Portable Class library to have common functionality across all platforms. my problem is that when I try to reuse my code inside PCL I can not access some methods and properties inside library. According to MSDN those methods are supported but I do know now why I can not access them.

```
        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {}
```

here is the fragment of the code that can not be compiled. GetGetMethod and IsStatic are in red inside Visual Studio editor. I have no idea why is that happening and how to access those properties.

so please if anyone out there has ever done something like that, help me to make this code compile.

Comment: use Type.GetMethod http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx

Comment: What is the debugger sayig?

Comment: GetMethod and GetGetMethod are tow different things so why should i use GetMethod?
Compiler says that it can't resolve symbol GetGetMethod.
This problem is if target platform is Windows Phone 8

Comment: There have been some changes to the reflection API in .NET 4.5 for apps targeting either PCL or Windows Store. The following blog entry provides a nice walk-through of the changes: `http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx`. Notably: GetMethod and siblings are no longer available. Use the `DeclaredMethod(s)` property instead (available on `TypeInfo` instances, which you can get from a type instance using `.GetTypeInfo()`).

Comment: Scroll down to the `Writing code for the new reflection API – Windows Store and Portable Class Library` to find the information you need (but I'd recommend reading the whole blog post).

Comment: Are u sure you provided correct URL? I can not access it.

Comment: Try this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx (link is the same as before, but seems SO prefers them unquoted)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We did some refactoring in the reflection APIs for .NET for Windows Store apps.  See the blog post [Evolving the Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) for details.  Among other things, the API changes set us up for better portability in the future.  The new APIs are available in Windows Store apps, .NET 4.5 and Windows Phone 8.  For compatibility, the old APIs are of course still available on .NET 4.5 and Windows Phone 8.

For Portable Class Libraries, if you target *only* platforms where the new reflection APIs are supported, then you will get only the new APIs.  If you add a platform that doesn't support the new APIs then you will get the APIs.

`PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()` isn't part of the new APIs, so you should use `PropertyInfo.GetMethod` instead.  `MethodInfo.IsStatic` is part of the new APIs, the reason you saw red squiggles in Visual Studio there was because it didn't know what type getMethod was because you used `var` and GetGetMethod() wasn't recognized.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
    var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null)
    {
    }

    var getMethod = property.GetMethod;
    if (getMethod != null && getMethod.IsStatic)
    {}
```

Comment: As an aside, are there plans to support Reflection.Emit in PCL at any point?

Comment: Complete and exact answer!!! thank u very much u made my life much more easier now

Comment: @MortenMertner Reflection.Emit is already supported in Portable Class Libraries that target .NET 4.5 and Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

To provide some info about my comment **use Type.GetMethod**.

**Metadata from Type**

> When evaluating metadata returned from `System.Type` methods and
>   properties, the equality operator may return different results on
>   different platforms. In the .NET Compact Framework, each successive
>   call to the `Type.GetMethod` method returns a new instance of
>   `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`, so return values are never evaluated as
>   equal. However, in the .NET Framework 4, calling `GetMethod` with the
>   same parameters returns the same instance of MethodInfo. You must
>   review and potentially modify your code when you are working with the
>   following System.Reflection types: `MethodInfo`, `FieldInfo`,
>   `PropertyInfo`, `EventInfo`, `MemberInfo`, `MethodBase`, `ConstructorInfo`, and
>   `ParameterInfo`.

**Reflection on Open Generic Types**

> On Windows Phone 7, reflection is supported on closed generic types;
>   however, most reflection operations are not supported on open generic
>   types. On open generic types, only the following reflection operations
>   are supported for Windows Phone 7: Retrieving an open generic type or
>   method by calling the `GetType` or `GetMethods` method. Creating a generic
>   type or method from an open generic type or method by calling the
>   `MakeGenericType` or `MakeGenericMethod` method. For all other reflection
>   operations on open generic types, a `NotSupportedException` exception is
>   thrown.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597392.aspx

Comment: the same question, why to use GetMethod when GetGetMethod is different then GetMethod?