# Test if a property is an ICollection in Portable class library

Tags: c#, reflection, portable-class-library

iam trying to test if a property of my object is a collection or not but encounter problem since in portable class library many method are not avaible

this is my method:

```
public virtual bool Equals(TObject other) // where TObject : class
{
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    Type t = GetType();
    Type otherType = other.GetType();

    TypeInfo typeInfo = t.GetTypeInfo();            

    if (t != otherType)
        return false;

    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields; 
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    { ...
```

now i have to test if field is an Icollection or not but

- ImplementedInterfaces is not avaible
- IsAssignableFrom is not avaible
- GetInterfaces() is not avaible
- GetGenericTypeDefinition() is not avaible

maybe this is because i have FieldInfo and not TypeInfo?

is there something i can do?

Comment: There's a new reflection API for use in PCLs.  See the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061291/portable-class-library-and-reflection go read the blog post.

Comment: i read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/ in fact i use it for DeclaredFields but now can't see how to get what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it excludind this type via linq Linq

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = typeInfo.DeclaredFields.Where(x => x.FieldType.Name != typeof(ICollection<>).Name);
```